# Remember last used function / store a function in a variable?

Tags: vb.net, function, pointers, hotkeys

I have a program that automates certain processes to save time, things like selecting a random choice from a list, selecting multiple random choices from a list, copying my social media links to the clipboard, etc. I set up a few global hotkeys for my most frequently used functions, and the rest of them can be chosen from a ContextMenuStrip. It takes longer to right click and select an item from a ContextMenuStrip than it does to press a hotkey, obviously.

I want to add a hotkey that will execute to most recently selected option from the ContextMenuStrip. That way, if I want to perform a certain function 10 times in a row, I can choose it from the ContextMenuStrip *once* and then simply press the hotkey 9 times for the rest. How can I achieve this?

Comment: This might take a bit of research on your part but what you could do is, instead of calling your functions directly, you could create a delegate and invoke that.  A delegate is an object that refers to a method so you can assign that object to a variable and access it again later. In fact, I normally wouldn't do this when someone has posted no code but this is likely completely alien to you so I'll create an example and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

For the example below, create a new WinForms application project and add a `TextBox`, a `Button` and `ContextMenuStrip`.  Add three items to the menu and name them "First", "Second" and "Third".  Assign the `ContextMenuStrip` to the `ContextMenuStrip` property of the form.

```
Public Class Form1

    'A delegate referring to the method to be executed.
    Private method As [Delegate]

    'An array of arguments to be passed to the method when executed.
    Private arguments As Object()

    Private Sub FirstToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FirstToolStripMenuItem.Click
        'Execute Method1 with no arguments.
        method = New Action(AddressOf Method1)
        arguments = Nothing
        ExecuteMethod()
    End Sub

    Private Sub SecondToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SecondToolStripMenuItem.Click
        'Execute Method2 with text from a TextBox as arguments.
        method = New Action(Of String)(AddressOf Method2)
        arguments = {TextBox1.Text}
        ExecuteMethod()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ThirdToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ThirdToolStripMenuItem.Click
        'Execute Method3 with no arguments.
        method = New Action(AddressOf Method3)
        arguments = Nothing
        ExecuteMethod()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'Execute again the last method executed.
        ExecuteMethod()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ExecuteMethod()
        If method IsNot Nothing Then
            'Invoke the current delegate with the current arguments.
            method.DynamicInvoke(arguments)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Method1()
        MessageBox.Show("Hello World", "Method1")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Method2(text As String)
        MessageBox.Show(text, "Method2")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Method3()
        MessageBox.Show("Goodbye Cruel World", "Method3")
    End Sub

End Class
```

You can now right-click the form and select a menu item to execute one of the three methods named `Method1`, `Method2` and `Method3`.  If you click the `Button`, it will re-execute whichever of those was last executed.

I've also shown how you can execute method with and without arguments.  Just note that, in this case, clicking the `Button` after selecting the "Second" menu item will execute `Method2` with whatever the `TextBox` contained at the time it was first executed rather than what it contains now.  If you needed to use the current value then you'd retrieve it inside the method rather than pass it as an argument.  I just included that part so I could demonstrate passing arguments to the delegates.